# How to perform a "Select all" via keyboard, in recent versions of Gnome Terminal?

Tags: 15.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, shortcuts, 15.10

In (X)Ubuntu 14.04, I was able to perform a `Select All` operation via keyboard, in Gnome Terminal, invoking the menu (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> -> <kbd>A</kbd>).

With more recent versions of (X)Ubuntu, I've noticed that the shortcuts for the menu bar are not available anymore.

For some operations, it's possible to set a direct shortcut (eg. `Reset and clear terminal`), but not for `Select All`.

Is there a way I can perform this operation via keyboard?

Note: I refer strictly to Gnome Terminal, not other terminal applications.

Comment: I've filed a bug here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=757512

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like that option has been voluntarily removed.

The closest I can get to get something similar is enabling "Enable mnemonics (such as Alt+F to open the File menu)" in Edit > Preferences:

[image: screenshot]

And use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>↓</kbd>,<kbd>↓</kbd>,<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to select all.

Answer (score 7):

Enable e.g. <kbd>Shift + Ctrl + A</kbd> as the shortcut key for *Select All* in *Preferences → Shortcuts*.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Does't grab the scrollback buffer.